# How to search a 2d array to find max and mins in columns using pointers in standard C?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

today I have a problem with searching a max and min value in a column. I did it with a row, but with columns something went wrong. It's a task for university, so I have to operate using pointers. So I wrote a function:

```
int column_statistics(const int *ptr, int width, int height, int column_id, int* max, int* min, float *avg){

  //problem generator
      if(ptr==NULL || width<=0 || height<=0 || column_id<0 || max==NULL || min==NULL || avg==NULL || column_id>(--width)){
        return 1;
  }

  int maximal;
  int minimal;
  int sum=0;

  for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
    printf("%d ",*(ptr+column_id*width+i));
    sum+=*(ptr+column_id*width+i);
    if(i==0){
      minimal=*(ptr+column_id*width+i);
      maximal=*(ptr+column_id*width+i);
      continue;
    }

    if(*(ptr+column_id*width+i)<maximal && *(ptr+column_id*width+i)>minimal){
      continue;
    }
    else if(*(ptr+column_id*width+i)>maximal){
      maximal=*(ptr+column_id*width+i);
    }
    else if(*(ptr+column_id*width+i)<minimal){
      minimal=*(ptr+column_id*width+i);
    }
  }

  *max=maximal;
  *min=minimal;
  *avg=(float)sum/(float)height;
  return 0;
}
```

I think that it is OK, but when I am testing this in main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int column_statistics(const int *ptr, int width, int height, int column_id, int* max, int* min, float *avg);


int main(void) {


  int input_array[3][5] = {{ 11, 81, -86, -63, 79}, { 94, -9, 11, -22, 72}, { 64, -61, 33, -36, -73}};
  int *ptr = input_array[0];
  int max, min, test;
  float a;


  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", *(ptr+i*5),*((ptr+i*5)+1),*((ptr+i*5)+2),*((ptr+i*5)+3),*((ptr+i*5)+4));
  }
  puts("============================================");
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    column_statistics(ptr, 5, 3, i, &max, &min, &a);
    printf("Column %d: %d %d %.2f | Test: %d\n", ++i, max, min, a, test);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Something goes wrong and in output I have something like this:

(The inputed 2d-array)
11 81 -86 -63 79
94 -9 11 -22 72
64 -61 33 -36 -73

(The actual output of a function, the first string are the numbers that were in the function, than there is a max and min from column, average of a column, and test from "problem generator")

11 81 -86 -63 Column 1: 81 -86 -19.00 | Test: 0

79 94 -9 11 Column 2: 94 -9 58.33 | Test: 0

-22 72 64 -61 Column 3: 72 -61 17.67 | Test: 0

So the problem is that function loads only 4 variable instead of 5, but I don't know if the problem is in main or in the column_statistics. Guys, if you see what is wrong please, report this. Have a nice day and thanks for your time.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you don't want negative numbers use an `unsigned` data type.

Comment: On another unrelated note, for any pointer (or array) `ptr` and index `i`, the expression `*(ptr+i)` is ***exactly*** equal to `ptr[i]`. Using the latter syntax (`ptr[i]`) is usually easier to understand and read, not to mention it's less to write.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to the condition `column_id>(--width)`. That `--width` will modify the value of the variable. If you passed `5` for `width`, after `--width` the value will be `4`.

That will affect your loops where you iterate using `width`, like for example the very first loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
```

It will also affect all calculation you have suing width, like for example `*(ptr+column_id*width+i)`.

If you want to compare `column_id` with `width - 1` then use `width - 1` instead (like `column_id>(width-1)`).